# Is there any way to get the SSL status of a website using fetch in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ssl, https, certificate

Is there any way to get the SSL certificate status with fetch in ReactJS?

I wanna check if a website is using SSL or not with JS. I tried checking the response.url from the response but there are cases where a website has https but it says certificate expired. Can I get that information with fetch?

If not, is there any other solution?

Comment: Nope unfortunately. I am looking to just test different websites by making a fetch to them and seeing if they use SSL certificate.

Comment: Hi Marti, are you trying to get the expiration date of the certificates? Maybe try [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9679920/check-ssl-certificate-expiration-date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9679920/check-ssl-certificate-expiration-date).