# Does chrome think the current page is secure?

Tags: javascript

How to find out if chrome show a security warning for the user about the current page not been secure?

[image: Not Secure]

I been trying to use `window.isSecureContext` and check whether the location protocol is **https** but all turns out as true even so I can see the warring in my Chrome browser. So is there any way to get this information?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check in Javascript if a SSL Certificate is valid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2618944/check-in-javascript-if-a-ssl-certificate-is-valid)

Comment: Why would a clientside script need to test this?

Comment: @Bergi because the client is a bank, and if Chrome think that the page is not secure the client want to be aware of that and show the proper message to the user.

Comment: @Ilya_Gazman A user wouldn't believe any message from a page hist browser told him not to trust? It's too late anyway when the page arrives at the user with invalid certificates, the bank architecture should be properly designed so that this never happens. If it's just about monitoring the server certificates, the bank doesn't need to do it with JS.

Comment: @Bergi There nothing server can do against men in the middle attack, there is no way to verify the client in js. So once the browser sees it, I would like to shut down the site for that user.

Comment: You cannot protect the user from a mim attack, a mim could remove any script that "shuts the side down". The "not secure" alert from Chrome itself is the only message that the user can rely on; you might want to educate them about that though.

Comment: @Bergi Yeah the attacker can change anything in the site, but this is not a reason for a site to not want to protect it self as much as it can

Comment: Given it's pretty much pointless, there is no API that allows you to access this information

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is No! It is impossible. Javascript is a clinet side language to deal with objects not communicate with servers and validate certificates.

The only possible thing is to check whether the protocol is https or not. The one that you see is actually a function something like this:

```
window.iSSecureContext = function() {return document.location.protocol == 'https'; }
```

Comment: JavaScript is a general-purpose language and can be used for much more than "dealing with clientside objects" (including communication with servers), the question is rather whether a browser environment hosts the necessary interfaces.

Comment: it must be `window.iSSecureContext = function() {return document.location.protocol == 'https:'; }`