# How to implement single sign on in angular2 application

Tags: javascript, angular, authentication, typescript

I have a web application built using angular2 and I need to provide single sign on feature to my application. We don't want the user to key in login credentials, application should use user's windows credentials while trying to access it. I have no idea on how to get windows credentials using javascript/typescript from client.

Any ideas on implementing this functionality is much appreciated.

Comment: Is this an IIS web server or is it Apache?

Comment: its Apache tomcat

Comment: The moderators are going to mark your question insufficient for the rules of this forum. You need to put in the research time and show what you need help with. This isn't a "do my job for me" kind of site.

Answer (score 0):

What I would suggest is to get the User client SSL for authenticating. That is the best way to do that. You need to send SSL to user(In Enterprise users normally all laptop\desktop have user certificates) and use it as SSO.

You may also ask user to install certificate if not available.

[Check in Javascript if a SSL Certificate is valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2618944/check-in-javascript-if-a-ssl-certificate-is-valid)