# Angular. Digital certificate

Tags: angular, certificate

i am a new angular developer.

I need a make angular web site, this site has a validate user with digital certificate.

This is possible in Angular 6.2.5? how to make?

Thanks.

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25077676/9386929

Answer (score 0):

Maybe some research would help.

You could use something like this I guess - https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-client-certificate (this would be backend) or another one https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-client-cert, in addition some examples
http://www.passportjs.org/packages/passport-client-cert/